# Находится ли значение переменной в заданном интервале чисел

Tags: powershell

Как выполнить сравнение является ли `$split[0]` числом от `0..9`?

```
$max=$sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
for ($i=9; $i -le $max; $i++){
    $row2 = $sheet.Cells.Item($i,6).text
    $split=$row2 -split "(.)" -ne ""
    if($split[0]            ){
        [void]$sheet.Cells.Item($i,1).EntireRow.Delete()
        $i--
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться методом `Contains`. Вот так:

```
@(0..9).Contains([Int]$split[0])

@(0..9).Contains(5)
True

@(0..9).Contains(123)
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно, например, использовать оператор `-in`:

```
$split[0] -in 0..9
```

Или метод `Contains`:

```
(0..9).Contains($split[0])
```

Примеры для фанатов LINQ (работает в PS -ge 4):

```
[Linq.Enumerable]::Any([Int32[]](0..9), [Func[Int32, Boolean]]{param($x) $x -eq 7})
# или
[Linq.Enumerable]::Contains([Int32[]](0..9), 7)
```

Вариантов на самом деле очень много.